# Session in service cloud console

Tags: service-cloud-console, session

We are using Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit in service cloud console and currently have issues with multiple tabs opening up in production .The tabs opened in previous session are retained causing issues to the user.

We tried using sforce.console.closeTab method but it does not work in the browser .So we want to know if their is way to close all the tabs from the previous session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you goto Setup -> Create -> Apps -> [Your Console App], there is a setting `Save User Sessions`. Try clearing that box and that should remove the open tabs when you logs off and logs back in.

Comment: Tnx.  Tht helps.